# Вызов процедуры содержащей insert используя pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, insert

Доброго времени суток. Возникла необходимость использовать pyodbc для работы с бд. Вопрос в том: как выполнить процедуру содержащую много insert комманд.

Comment: под процедурой вы понимаете набор insert запросов в коде программы, или хранимую процедуру на стороне СУБД, выполняющую много insert-запросов?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, код будет следующий:

```
def multiinsert(cursor, selector, values): 
    for value in values:
        cursor.execute(selector, value)


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=host.com;DATABASE=mydb;UID=user;PWD=secret')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#cоздали соеденение и курсор

selector = '''
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?);
'''
#этот код будет выполняться на стороне SQL сервера

values_list = [(1, 'a', 10), (2, 'q', 78), (17, 'z', 46)]
#значения из кортежей будут подставляться в селектор выше.
#например, в ходе первой итерации на стороне sql исполнится запрос
#INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (1, 'a', 10);

multiinsert(cursor, selector, values_list)
```

Для того, чтобы вызвать процедуру хранимую на сервере:

```
params = (42, "coach")
cursor.execute("{CALL my_procedure (?,?)}", params) #вызов процедуры с параметрами
cursor.execute("{CALL my_procedure_noparam}") #вызов процедуры без параметров
```

Comment: Не совсем. У меня уже есть написанная процедура в sql server с insert, корректно работающая в sql server. Её надо просто вызвать с помощью python

Comment: @Banifest, добавил нужный Вам код

Comment: Проблема не в вызове процедуры. А то что процедуры с dml операциями( insert, update, delete) при вызове из под python не выполняются именно под этим драйвером. У пользователя есть права на их выполнение. Под другими программами (SQL management studio) или драйвером(pymssql)  выполняется.

Comment: Приведите Ваш код python и код процедуры. И что именно происходит: выподает исключение, результат работы функции отличается от ожидаемого?

Comment: На случай, если будет ошибка `ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.`, в самом начале запроса добавьте: `SET NOCOUNT ON`.